# Is it possible to change UIBarButtonItem title and style in runtime?

Tags: iphone

In one project, I hope to change UIBarButtonItem and style in runtime

editBarItemButton links to a UIBarButtonItem which original status are

style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
title:Edit

if I press the bar item button, it will execute the codes below:

```
[editBarItemButton setStyle: UIBarButtonItemStyleDone];
[editTarBarItemButton setTitle:@"Done"  ];
```

but neither the style nor title has changed.

Welcome any comment

Thanks
interdev

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot change the style of a `UIBarButtonItem` after it has already been initialized.

Answer (score 4):

Old thread, but I am successful in changing the title for a UIBarButton item in a Navigation controller using the following:

```
[[[self navigationItem] rightBarButtonItem] setTitle:@"List"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the old buttons
Create new buttons with the styles you want
Set the new buttons

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is something like this (that preserves localization for you app as well):

```
- (void)setBarButtonTo:(int)type
{
    UIBarButtonItem *add = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:type     target:self action:nil];
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:add];
}
```

Where type is one of the system supplied, as `UIBarButtonSystemItemDone` or `UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit`. Hope this helps. :)

PS: I'm aware it's an old question, but it lacked a proper answer.

Comment: Oh, this is ARC, btw. Remember to dealloc the previous one if you're not using ARC.